# Painted Scene with Lighting

Tags: texture-painting, lighting

I have a more general question about lighting a scene with painted material.

Since I have created a scene in which I want to paint all the textures I am now confused after watching some tutorials. People always draw lights and shadows on the objects. But when I decide to change my lighting setup wouldnt I have to start over? I can not really describe what I am meaning so I will explain it in a picture.

[image]

Lets say I was painting my cube like in case A. Now the lighting changes and comes from the right like in case B. Sine I painted the object like the light would come from the left.. it now wont fit when the light comes from any other angle and casts shadows in a different direction. 
So when I am doing a full scene do i just have to accept that it is just used for one lighting setup?

Comment: Really people are doing it that way? I'm looking at YouTube tutorials about Texture Painting and can't find anyone who are doing that. For me it's kind a  pointless.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L7ALfRw6I5I

He puts shadow at the bottom of the thing at the top. And when the light would now come from the bottom it would be totally senseless having shadow there. so I am wondering ..

Comment: In addition to Mzidare: depending on the context you use the object in, some baked lightmaps might be no problem. For a RTS game the main light source is usually the sun. The more dynamic the lightning gets, the less lightmaps one should use, especially with hard shadows.

Comment: Painting lighting information on texture would only make sense if lighting does not change. This may provide some stylized look but it would be better to paint diffuse/albedo/(even AO in some cases) on to the textures and leave lighting calculations for the renderer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look closer to this tutorials, you'll notice, that they don't really paint lighting conditions but more like Ambient occlusion and some highlights, that are similar for each side of the object. In the tutorial you linked to, you can see the same amount of shadow under the top part on each side, The same with the highlights on cracks and tiles. The same on each side.Try to copy this effect while creating your painted textures. This will suggest some details, but won't interfere too much with added lighting.